# jaxb required + defaultValue

Tags: java, jaxb

I've been wondering, is there any point in marking a field both as required and with a default value.

```
public class MyClass {
  @XmlElement(name = "my-element", required = true, defaultValue = "Hello world")
  protected String myElement;
}
```

Am I correct that the `required` condition can never be broken, because a default value will be applied whenever that happens ?

Comment: The `required` parameter will only affect whether the XSD will have `minOccurs="0"` or `minOccurs="1"` for that particular element. I suspect that any actual differences would occur if you're validating XML with it. JAXB would parse XML without the element, but validating it would fail if `required=true`.